# Updating entity using Java Streams API

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am performing an update operation on the user object based on the userid using streams API. Below is the code that I have written.
Is there a better way to refactor the code as I need to again fetch the updated user and send.

```
public User updateUser(int userId, User user){
        System.out.println("User id is "+ userId);
       this.userRepository
                .fetchUserByUserId(userId)
                .map(u -> {
                    u.setUserId(user.getUserId());
                    u.setUsername(user.getUsername());
                    u.setEmailAddress(user.getEmailAddress());
                    return u;
                });
        return this.userRepository.fetchUserByUserId(userId).get();
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of the value returned by method `fetchUserByUserId`? Is it [Stream<User>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)? Or is it [List<User>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)?

Comment: I guess, it’s rather `Optional<User>`. Further, the line `u.setUserId(user.getUserId());` raises some question marks. Are you really updating the ID? Which object are you actually updating then, the one with the ID `userId` or the one with the ID `user.getUserId()`? In the latter case, is the second `fetchUserByUserId(userId)` really supposed to return the object with `user.getUserId()`? Or are both IDs supposed to be the same anyway and the statement `u.setUserId(user.getUserId());` is redundant? Why does `User` have a `setUserId` method at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any reason to fetch again

You can map user to updated user and to return the new one.

```
public User updateUser(int userId, User user){
        System.out.println(String.format("UserId is %s",userId));
        return this.userRepository
                .fetchUserByUserId(userId)
                .map(u -> this.mergeUsers(u,user));
        
    }

   public User mergeUsers(Optional<User> dbUser, User newUser){
    if(dbUser.isPresent())
      return user.builder()
             .emailAddress(newUser.getEmailAddress())
             .username(newUser.getUsername()).build();
   else
      // Do something else. 
  }

// Setting Id is irrelevant cause it is same value.. youre fetching by this value.
```

Comment: Is there any other nice way to setting the user in the map method other than having a lamdba block?

Comment: @zilcuanu You can move it to another method.

Comment: we are using the `isPresent()` check. Can we do it using any functional style using Stream operator?